# Do we have a sandbox for questions?

Tags: support

Some SO sites do have a sandbox for questions (for example Code Golf)...

There are some interpretative questions I would like to ask, but since they cannot be answered via Word of God, there is always the chance people will misunderstand and flag/downvote it just by skimming it.

So, is there a sandbox in anime.se?

Comment: For now our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) would be the best option. The is because we don't get the same volume of request as the sites you've mentions and that many of the more frequennt users tend to hang out in the chatroom more than meta -- optimizing the visibility and response to the nature of your prospective question.

Answer (score 5):

That would be [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-).

Answer (score 1):

If there is doubt, user can double check their question here on meta before asking, like in StackOverflow. Well, or as @ton.yeung suggested, in chat room.

There is no need for a dedicated sandbox. CodeGolf's requirement is different, since they need to check the loopholes in the question and evaluate whether the challenge is doable, not duplicated before and interesting. Our questions don't require such stringent quality check, and the frequent edits (and close votes if applicable) are enough to keep the site quality in check.